# Append every 2nd element of list (Python)

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am working on a card game challenge. I made 3 classes: a "Card:" class, a "Deck:" class, and a "Player:" class.

In the deck class is a function to create a deck(list) full of cards
in the player class is an empty list (e.g. "self.hand = []")

To save on space, I won't show all the classes' full codes, but here are the key pieces:

In the Deck class:

```
# Deal one card
def deal_one(self):
    return self.deck.pop(0)
```

In the Player class:

```
# Take a card:
def take(self, new_cards):
    if type(new_cards) == type([]):
        self.hand.extend(new_cards)
    else:
        self.hand.append(new_cards)
```

It's easy enough to create 2 players and split the deck down the middle between them as follows:

```
for card in range(26):
    pl_1.take(mydeck.deal_one())
    pl_2.take(mydeck.deal_one())
```

but as a challenge, I wanted to deal every second card to each player.
I tried this:

```
for card in mydeck.deck[::2]:
    pl_1.take(mydeck.deal_one())
```

But this returned the same result as the first code (first half of deck given to player 1).
Can anyone help with a fix? Thanks!

Comment: As I see there is no chance that the last function produces any thing different. Because the variable card is not involved within the task done by the function. Thus, what mater is only the size of mydeck.deck[::2]. If this later is identical to range(26) your code will return exactly the same things/

Comment: Have you tried something like this

for card in range(52):
    if card % 2 == 0:
        pl_1.take(mydeck.deal_one())
    else:
        pl_2.take(mydeck.deal_one())

Comment: user639467, your solution works. I had thought of something like it, but was thinking I had to somehow define the list index position, which threw me off because I didn't know what the syntax would be. I see how the "range" function removes the need to define a list index. Good stuff. Many thanks!

Comment: If you post it as an official answer, I'll give you a check and a vote up

Answer (score 0):

In your deck class, add a function that accepts a List of players and use a modulo to alternate between players.

Bonus: accept an int to break the for loop after maximum cards per player is reached.

```
def takeAlternate(players : list, maxCardsPerPlayer : int = 0):
      numPlayers = len(players)
      currentCard = 0
      currentPlayer = 0
      for card in self.deck:
        currentPlayer = currentCard % numPlayers
        # move card from deck to player
        players[currentPlayer].takeCard(card)
        self.deck.remove(card)
        currentCard += 1
        if maxCardsPerPlayer != 0 and currentCard >= maxCardsPerPlayer * numPlayers:
            break
```

Comment: This probably works, but it's a lot of steps and a lot of code for what is probably a really simple task.